# Deferred implementation for jQuery Ajax global handlers

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, promise, jquery-events

According to jQuery documentation, the [global Ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) must be implemented using callback functions on the document. Otherwise, local [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) implement events using [promises](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Is there any way of handling the global Ajax events using promises method, as [.done()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/), [.fail()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/), [.always()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) and [.then()](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) ?

I'm looking for a way for declaring event handlers for global ajax events that do not depend on `$(document)`, for example:

```
// current way of doing this:
// $(document).ajaxSuccess(_handleAjaxSuccess);
// 
// some ideas of what it could look like:
// $.ajaxSuccess(_handleAjaxSuccess);
// $.ajax.done(_handleAjaxSuccess);
// $.ajaxSetup({ done: _handleAjaxSuccess });
```

Comment: Please explain what you are wanting to do in more detail

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot handle the global Ajax events using promises method `.done()`, `.fail()`, `.always()` and `.then()`.

Those are Promise methods, therefore a Promise needs to exist before before they become available.

By definition, jQuery's global ajax event handlers are not attached to any particular Promise at the point where they are defined. Instead, they are stored by jQuery and invoked internally *whenever* certain ajax events occur.

As users of jQuery, we don't need to worry about how those internal invocations are made but we can be pretty sure that one or other of the methods `.done()`, `.fail()`, `.always()` and `.then()` is involved.

If you want to know more, you can delve into the jQuery source, however I doubt that the extra understanding would be particularly valuable.

Comment: Hi, @Roamer, I actually already delved into jquery source code and got support from jquery forum. It is not supported, but it _feels_ strange that some global handling for Ajax is done on jquery context (`$`) and some are done on the document context (`$(document)`).

Comment: If it helps, they *could* have written the API such that we call something like `jQuery.addGlobalAjaxHandler('complete', function() {...})`, making the attachment to `document` invisible to us. For some reason (probably historical) they have ended up where they are. I think it's just a question of accepting the *status quo*. Personally, have no problem with that, though at one time my mindset was just like yours. It's an age thing.

Answer (score 0):

Although the promises interface is supported on `jqXHR` instances, it is not supported on global Ajax events on jquery and currently there's no plan to implementing it ([jquery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/is-there-any-promisses-interface-for-ajax-global-events)).